# admin-ajax.php loading many times

Tags: php, functions, wp-admin

My site is running slow, because the file "admin-ajax.php" is loaded many times. see screenshot here:
http://f.cl.ly/items/2b0O3Q0X27433X2F2j3U/Bildschirmfoto%202013-02-23%20um%2014.13.14.png

Here the functions.php file: 
http://f.cl.ly/items/3e2D070u2M310W1J321K/Bildschirmfoto%202013-02-23%20um%2014.19.46.png

How can i disable the file on the frontend and why is it loaded so many times?! Can i reduce it to only ONE time?

Thanks!

Comment: You do not want to disable `admin-ajax.php`. You will break all kinds of things. Looks to me like you have a very poorly written theme or plugin. I can't tell which. You need to find out what is causing those requests. They aren't normal. Switch to a default theme and disable you plugins one by one and try to isolate the problem.

Comment: Or click on one of those and check out the headers tab, and the request params. IT might be obvious where the issue is from there. You can also look at the response tab to see what data is coming back, which might also make it obvious.

Comment: Thanks a lot! The plugin zilla-likes caused the problem. thank you!

Comment: I would like to add you should not disable admin-ajax.php since it handles AJAX requests. It's likely more than just the one plugin causing it to have problems uses the file and you will incur even more problems with your website. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For everybody else:
It has been the plugin zilla-likes in combination with the Hoarder Theme. 
I deactivated the plugin.